# RxJS custom scheduler for requestAnimationFrame

Tags: rxjs

I know rxjs has a built in `animationFrameScheduler`, but i am pretty sure i can not use it to accomplish what I am wanting.

Essentially I am wanting to throttle some events by `requestAnimationFrame`. How I would do this in a subscribe is:

```
let taskId;

fromEvent(...)
.subscribe(args => {

  if (taskId) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(taskId);
  }

  taskId = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    performMyAction(args);
    taskId = null;
  });
});
```

What is happening is I want to throttle the events and only execute the last event per animationFrame.

I have tried `throttleTime(0, animationFrameScheduler)` and `observeOn(animationFrameScheduler)` and neither seem to do what I want.

My next thought was to just create a custom scheduler that could do this. I understand that I should create a class that implements `ScheduleLike`, but after that there seems to be no documentation on what the different methods of that class are supposed to do and what the parameters mean.

Furthermore attempting to read the source code of existing schedulers is an opaque mess of inheritance and wasn't useful is implementing my own.

So my questions is either; how can i use `animationFrameScheduler` to actually throttle my events in this way, or how can I learn how to build my own scheduler?

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for a stackblitz

Comment: what do you mean by  'only execute the last event per animationFrame.'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Built in [`animationFrame` scheduler](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/animationFrameScheduler) combined with [`audit` operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/audit) to get last value from the silenced time window should do the job.

See code example:

```js
const { of, from, animationFrameScheduler, asyncScheduler, interval } = rxjs;
const { audit, toArray } = rxjs.operators;
 
 const numbers = Array.from({ length: 100 }).map((_, i) => i);

from(numbers, asyncScheduler).pipe(
  audit(e => of(null, animationFrameScheduler))
).subscribe(e => console.log(e));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.5.3/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes! this works, thanks. don't know why i didn't think of that. i ended up using `auditTime(0, animationFrameScheduler)` and that behaves exactly as i was expecting.